# Observable object not displaying some properties

Tags: knockout.js

I have a viewmodel like this,

```
        function viewModel() {
            this.Items = ko.observable({ A : 1, B: 2 });
            this.Items.X = 4;
            this.Items.Y = 5;
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

I am printing out the values like this,

```
        <span data-bind="text: $root.Items['A']"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: $root.Items['B']"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: $root.Items['X']"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: $root.Items['Y']"></span>
```

X and Y values are displayed, but A and B values are empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting X and Y as part of the observable function, instead of the object being observed.

```
function viewModel() {
   this.Items = ko.observable({ A : 1, B: 2 });
   this.Items().X = 4;
   this.Items().Y = 5;
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

this.Items() will provide access to the object.

```
<span data-bind="text: $root.Items()['A']"></span>
<span data-bind="text: $root.Items()['B']"></span>
<span data-bind="text: $root.Items()['X']"></span>
<span data-bind="text: $root.Items()['Y']"></span>
```