# Dynamically adding data to observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I have this viewmodel and a function to add data to it,

```
        function viewModel() {
            this.loadData = function() {
                this.Items().push('X');
                this.Items().push('Y');
            };

            this.Items = ko.observableArray(['A', 'B']);
        }

        var vm = new viewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
        vm.loadData();
        alert(vm.Items());
```

I am trying to print out the values in Items array, but X and Y are never displayed. Though the alert pops up A, B, X, and Y. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: {data: Items, as: 'item' }">
        <span data-bind="text: item"></span>
    </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.Items()` exposes the underlying array of `ko.observableArray()`, which is just a normal array. You need to use this:

```
this.Items.push('X');
this.Items.push('Y');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m7cku/)

Comment: I am a little confused on when to use this.Items and when to use this.Items()? I thought I should always use Items() - I posted a similar question yesterday, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992898/observable-object-not-displaying-some-properties

Comment: Use `this.Items` when you want the KnockOut 'magic' to happen when you change the contents of the array (`this.Items` *looks* like an array, but isn't really; it's a special KnockOut type which mimics an array; `this.Items()` returns the actual array where the data is stored, but it's not 'magic'). Your other question uses an observable, not an observableArray, which are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

You should push the data directly to this.Items.

this.Items() returns the content of the observableArray.